# Pandas any alternative way to check between

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns in the pandas data frame and want to check each index value is in between with the other two-column. my code

```
def check_between():
    data = {'Upper': [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
            'Value': [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
            'Lower': [19, 18, 21, 13, 14, 15, 30, 17, 18, 19, 20], }
    pds = panda.DataFrame().from_dict(data)
    print(pds)
    is_between = False
    for ind in pds.index:
        if pds['Upper'][ind] > pds['Value'][ind] > pds['Lower'][ind]:
            is_between = True
        else:
            is_between = False
            return is_between
    return is_between
```

Is it the correct and optimize way or any other pre-defined function is there?

Comment: Yes, it's `pds['Value'].between(pds['Lower'], pds['Upper'], inclusive=False)`

Comment: @QuangHoang - Can you post that as the answer?

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks, just one confusion this will return series so how to break and return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Pandas has a built-in function for check in between:

```
 betweens = pds['Value'].between(pds['Lower'], pds['Upper'], inclusive=False)
```

And the equivalence to your `check_between()` function is:

```
 betweens.all()
```